# HTML Editor from ASP.NET with file upload and insert

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms

I have a website that is ASP.NET Webforms VB.  I need to add to it a HTML text editor with file upload so images (for example) can be uploaded and inserted or selected from previously uploaded and inserted.

I have seen TinyMCE can do this but seemingly with me having to work on the Plugin.

Can anyone advise on something that can achieve the above but kind of working "out of the box"?

Free ideally but can look at commercial.

Again it is Webforms so not MVC or anyting like that.

HZ

Comment: Not sure of what you are asking but a asp:fileupload control will allow for uploads and you can filter on image (png, jpg, jpeg, gif)  extensions if that's important.

Comment: Open your 'index.cshtml' file or some other 'View.cshtml' file in your ASP.NET project to add an input element with type='file'. ( <input type="file" id="ImgFile" onchange="ImgUpload()"/> )

Comment: [CuteEditor](https://cutesoft.net/ASP.NET+WYSIWYG+Editor/) is an excellent tool. There is a free version that has some limit - I don't remember now what it is. As I recall the licensing is very reasonable though.

Answer (score 0):

The ajaxtool kit has two kinds of file uploaders, and also has a html editor, and the editor does have a up-load option that can be added as a custom button.

You can find the demos here, including the HTML editor:
http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.net/

You can install using nuget if you wish (the most easy).